# On xcode, how do I say the length of the screen

Tags: screen, xcode4.5

I would like to have an image appear in the middle of the screen. When I change the IOS simulator from an iPhone 4s to the 5, the image doesn't appear in the middle of the screen, it appears more to the top.

I am thinking there is a way to do something like: UIImageView.center.y = length of screen/2

Please let me know if there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to get the screen dimensions first with CGRect. Then you can use the CGRect to get the screens height and width.

```
CGRect screenSizeRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat width = screenSizeRect.size.width;
CGFloat height = screenSizeRext.size.height;
```